# Firebase returns array with undefined object after remove

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue when I remove an element from a Firebase database. The structure is as follows(just a sample):

```
{
  "users":
  [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Toma Broome"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Boyd Bolens"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the users list the connection is like this:

```
firebase.database().ref("/users/").on("value", snap => {
    users = snap.val();
    console.log( users ); // pay attention to this line
    usersLoop();
});
```

Then I render the elements on screen and I try to remove one:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${targetEl}`).remove();
```

The element is actually removed from the database if I check the Firebase console, but the users array includes `undefined` values and after deleting some elements it returns an object and not an array.

This is the console after deleting three elements that are in the first position of the database. What I mean is that I get the full list of users (which I'm uploading using a JSON file), I delete the first element, all other elements are then re-rendered in the DOM. Then I remove the first element again and finally when I remove the first element for a third time, I get an object from firebase and obviously nothing is rendered because the code is expecting an array

```
(5) [undefined × 1, Object, Object, Object, Object]
(5) [undefined × 2, Object, Object, Object]
Object {3: Object, 4: Object}
```

Also as you can see the array keeps returning a length of 5 when in the database there are less elements.

An option that I'm thinking about is to use Lodash to remove the undefined elements from the collection returned and/or turn it into an array, but that will defy any scalability option of the app looking into the future.

Finally what seems more odd than anything is that all of the sudden the database structure seems to change, when visually keeps looking exactly as it was.

This is the structure of the database on firebase

```
-users
 |-0
  |-id:0
  |-name:value
  |-otherprops:value
 |-1
  |-id:1
  |-name:value
  |-otherprops:value
```

Comment: Firebase neither stores nor returns arrays: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: @cartant While you're correct that Firebase doesn't store arrays, it does in many cases return an array of the stored values look like an array. But deleting items then messes that up. In fact, the case in this question is quite explicitly covered by the snippet "however, if we then delete a, b, and d," in the blog post.

Comment: If anyone else is interested in what "looks like an array" means, have a look at the [source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/v4.1.3/src/database/js-client/core/snap/ChildrenNode.js#L203-L210).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links provided by @cartant gave the answer.

Yes, firebase does tolerates array structures in it's data but is not recommended to use them unless the specific data is not going to mutate too much or at all. In my case (creating some sort of CRUD app) is not recommendable, just use objects end everything is ok. The thing is that if you upload a json file with an array in it, firebase will transform that into an object structure using integers as the key of each element in the array. Then when I started to remove elements and reached this point:

```
if (!opt_exportFormat && allIntegerKeys && maxKey < 2 * numKeys) {
  // convert to array.
  var array = [];
  for (var key in obj)
    array[key] = obj[key];

  return array;
} else {
  if (opt_exportFormat && !this.getPriority().isEmpty()) {
    obj['.priority'] = this.getPriority().val();
  }
  return obj;
}
```

After deleting a specific number of elements the code passed to the else part of the statement, which ultimately result in firebase returning an object creating the whole issue.

I ended up with this type of structure:

```
{
  "users":
  {
    "user_00": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Toma Broome"
    },
    "user_01": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Boyd Bolens"
    }
  }
}
```

And using lodash to loop through the object (or it could be a ***for in*** loop) I was able to get the data in the same way I was doing when using an array. Finally using an object structure I didn't got any more collections with undefined elements in it.

@cartant, thanks a lot!!! I definitely learn something with your comments. I hope that you could post an answer so I can mark it as the solution of the problem and upvote it, you earned it sir!!

Comment: When you're able to, accept your own answer; it explains the situation well. I'm glad the links were of some help.