# How can I run an array of data through firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, firebase

i have a data structure as below 
[image]

I created an array called new array with the IDs such as [19777873, 53399293]

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Agents').child(newarray[i]);

dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
           database = firebase.database();
           console.log("Testing if the array values are here \n" + newarray);
            // var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Agents').child(newarray[i]);
            dbRef.on('value', newAgents,  errData);
        }
     })
 }
```

New Agent function

```
function newAgents(data) { 

    var container = document.getElementById("team"); 
    container.innerHTML = '';

    data.forEach(function(AgentSnap) { // loop over all jobs
        var key = AgentSnap.AgentID;
        console.log(AgentSnap.key);
        var Agents = AgentSnap.val();
        var AgentCard = `
                <div class= "profilepics" id="${key}">
                <figure ><img src=${Agents.profilepicurl}><figcaption>${Agents.Fname}</figcaption></figure>
                </div>
            `;

        container.innerHTML += AgentCard;
    })
}
```

the problem I'm having now is that images(from {Agents.profilepicurl}) are being displayed and name (from {Agents.Fname}) are not being displayed. instead of name it shows "undefined" and no error is show in console. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894968/6680611

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange things happening in the first few lines of your code. You are setting the "on" listener twice (ignoring the resulting snapshot for the first listener), and you're awaiting authentication and setting a database object without using it. I am not absolutely certain about what you're trying to achieve, but would this work? It's a simplified version of what I think you're trying to do with the current code:

```
console.log("Testing if the array values are here \n" + newarray);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = '';

        database = firebase.database();

        for (agentId of newarray) {
            var dbRef = database.ref().child('Agents').child(newarray[i]);
            dbRef.on('value', newAgents);
        }
    }
})

function newAgents(AgentSnap) { 
    var container = document.getElementById("team"); 

    var key = AgentSnap.AgentID;
    console.log(AgentSnap.key);
    var Agent = AgentSnap.val();
    var AgentCard = `
                <div class= "profilepics" id="${key}">
                <figure ><img src=${Agent.profilepicurl}><figcaption>${Agent.Fname}</figcaption></figure>
                </div>
            `;

        container.innerHTML += AgentCard;
    }
```

Comment: it is using AuthId,
 Fname,
 Lname,
 email,
 language,
 phone,
 profilepicurl,
 resumeUrls, AgentSnap.key. What I want as key are 19777873, 53399293,..... how can this be implemented?